# SendBroadcast issue inside onCLickllistener

Tags: android, broadcast, clicklistener

```
btn2=(Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn2.setText("Find");

      btn2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent Message1=new Intent();
                Message1.setAction("map");
                sendBroadcast(Message1);}
```

The error says the method of broadcast is undefined inside the oclicklistener. why is that?

Comment: Are you running that inside an activity?

Answer (score 3):

Should be context.sendBroadcast(Intent). You can do CurrentActivity.this.sendBroadcast(Intent)
Inside of OnClickListener there is no context instance that's why it cannot execute method of Context

Answer (score 2):

You've created an `OnClickListener` as an anonymous class. Inside of this anonymous instance, you're trying to call `sendBroadcast()` and the compiler is trying to find such a method in `OnClickListener`, but there is no such method. What you need is to reference the enclosing class, namely the `Activity` by doing `ThisActivity.this.sendBroadcast(intent)`, where ThisActivity is the actual name of your `Activity`.

Answer (score 1):

`sendBroadcast` can only be done under an `Activity`, `BroadcastReceiver`, or `Service` context, but you are trying to `sendBroadcast` in the `onClick`, which is not any of the previously mentioned contexts.

The easiest thing to do is:

```
CurrentActivity.this.sendBroadcast(Message1);
```

Another option is to create a class variable `Context context` and then in the `onCreate` (if it's an activity or service), put `context = this`, and then do `context.sendBroadcast(Message1);`. Or, if it's in a `BroadcastReceiver`, just do `context.sendBroadcast(Message);`

Answer (score 1):

In Fragments

```
Intent signalIntent = new Intent("updateBTN");
signalIntent.putExtra("key", "value");
getActivity().sendBroadcast(signalIntent);
```

Comment: Not working, GetActivity is undefined